# Nested controls in LinkButton not clickable

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls, linkbutton, nested-controls

I am working on a Composite custom control.

In said control, I am inheriting from  LinkButton. In this LinkButton, I am nesting a Label Control and 5 Image controls.

I am able to render everything properly, and I´ve got the btton doing its on click events and everything, however, there´s a slight problem:

Once the button has rendered, the nested controls appear above the linkbutton, so that the linkbutton is not clickable where these added controls are...

What I want to know, is there a way to place them behind the linkbutton or something? So that the button is still clickable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend inheriting from CompositeControl, as that is the base class meant for situations like this.  Then you can render out the linkbutton at the point you want, and add it to the inner control collection.

Comment: Calling the composite control for this instance was too much work for the use i need the button to have, I simply inherited, as a component control, from the LinkButton, so i would already have all the functionalities of a button, and over everything, i placed a DIV with a javascript function to make the div clickablle.